# convert datetime string with month abbreviation to datetime object using lubridate

Tags: r, lubridate

How can I convert this string to datetime using `lubridate`? It has abbreviation of month.
The desired output is `12/1/2020 9:19:00 AM`

```
library(lubridate)

datetime_string = "01-DEC-2020 09:19 AM"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
datetime_string = "01-DEC-2020 09:19 AM"
timeValue <- lubridate::dmy_hm(datetime_string) 

format(timeValue, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p")
# "12/01/2020 09:19:00 AM"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `base R`

```
format(as.POSIXct(datetime_string, format = '%d-%b-%Y %H:%M %p'), '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p')
[1] "12/01/2020 09:19:00 am"
```